# LoadLibrary call System Error wpcap.dll

Tags: c++, dll, command-line-interface, loadlibrary

I'm trying to load a dll that I've made dynamically in another project. However when I go to load the library I get the following error message:

"The program can't start because wpcap.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

I've searched and haven't found a solution that works for me. I replaced that wpcap.dll file as well as a packet.dll file that it said was missing and it still gave me another error. If anyone could help me out with this I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a dependency walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) which you can use to find all the related dependencies of your program. You can use this to search for the missing dependencies. Use it on wpcap.dll. Using it on your .exe will not help much as the dependency walker doesn't find dependencies which using LoadLibrary call.

Answer (score 2):

Please reinstall [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm). It will put wpcap.dll (and its dependencies) into the Windows system directory. Then you can call LoadLibrary("wpcap.dll") in your code (there is no need to specify the path to the DLL).